# c++ private variable of a passed object

Tags: c++, private

```
#include <stdio.h>

class HelloClass
{
    float t;
public:
    HelloClass(float x) : t(x) {};
    float Add(HelloClass a);
};

float HelloClass::Add(HelloClass b)
{
    return t + b.t; // How is b.t accessible here?
}

int main()
{
    HelloClass a(2), b(3);
    printf("hello %f\n", a.Add(b));
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, the above code compiles. But I am not able to understand how `b.t` is accessible? Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: access specifiers (public private etc) apply to the code of the class, not to individual instances of the class. Thiis how it should be if you understand the purpose of access specifiers which is to separate interface from implementation. So the code in `HelloClass::Add` is part of the implementation of `HelloClass` therefore it has full access to any `HelloClass` object.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why it was designed this way? Why should the object (in above example: a) which is receiving a new object(b) for computation be allowed to access the internals of b? Is this a deviation in terms of encapsulation of a class?

Comment: No it's an implementation of encapsulation. Encapsulation is about separating interface from implementation. That has to do with code, not individual objects, as I said. So **code** not written by the author of the class has to use the public interface of the class, but code written by the author of the class can access the private implementation of the class.

Comment: Maybe that's slghtly confusingly put. The point is that you don't want code to break if the implementation of the class changes. So all code outside the class is forced to use the public interface, which doesn't change. But code inside the class is part of the implementation, so it needs no such restrictions.

Comment: However you want to put it, public/private, interface/implementation, encapsulation, data hiding, these are all features of code, not of objects. What we're trying to achieve is to minimise dependencies between different parts of the code.

Comment: For C++, perhaps `#include <iostream>` and then `std::cout << "hello " <<  a.Add(b) << '\n';` would be better than the C `printf` use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior, [`private` members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access#Private_member_access) could be accesed by member functions, even they're from other instances.

(emphasis mine)

> A `private` member of a class is only accessible to the members and
> friends of that class, **regardless of whether the members are on the
> same or different instances**:
>
> ```
> class S {
>   private:
>     int n; // S::n is private
>   public:
>     S() : n(10) {}                    // this->n is accessible in S::S
>     S(const S& other) : n(other.n) {} // other.n is accessible in S::S
> };
> ```